# Select values based on a variable number of criterion

Tags: python, pandas

Given:

- a dataset;
- attributes from that dataset( ex. gender, education level, etc)

I need to find all possible values of gender and education level:
ex *(Male,Bachelors)*.

I made a list of these tuples already.

Now I want to go back into the dataset and pick out the rows that have these specific values for gender and education level and some other attributes.

```
df1 = df[df['gender'] = 'Male' & df['education level'] = 'Bachelors']
```

but for all possible values of the attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your list of tuples are in a variable named `tups`

```
df.set_index(['gender', 'education']).loc[tups].reset_index()
```

Or

```
t = pd.Series(list(zip(df.gender, df.education)), df.index)
df[t.isin(tups)]
```

We can speed it up with

```
g = df.gender.values.tolist()
e = df.education.values.tolist()
z = list(zip(g, e))
s = pd.Series(z, df.index)
df[s.isin(tups)]
```